# Update on database should auto update in other sheets that has data retrieved from database

Tags: vba, excel

I have a dashboard containing a database containing up to three years worth of data and few sheets which the data used is from the database. Everytime, i update , add new data to the database i have to add it to the sheets manually as well. I did cell links but it does not apply to adding of data. Is there anyways in which everytime i add data to the a certain range in the database, it should automatically add in the sheet affected as well. I previously used this code, but recently the user told me that he does not want any loss of data. Is there any modifcations that could be made to do this? I need help with this as i have tried lot of methods already. Here is the code

```
Sub update()


MsgBox "Please ensure that the headers of the table are not selected when updating."

    Dim oselect As Range, vUndo As Variant
    On Error Resume Next
    Set oselect = Application.InputBox("Range?", , Selection.Address, , , , , 8)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If TypeName(oselect) <> "Range" Then
            Exit Sub
        Else
        oselect.Select
        vUndo = oselect
       Selection.Value = Selection.Offset(0, 1).Value

    If MsgBox("Save Changes?", vbYesNo) = vbNo Then
     oselect = vUndo
     End If

     End If

    End Sub
```

Comment: If this use-case is something that wouldn't be solved by adding a data connection to the database, can you describe more in detail?

Answer (score 0):

One solution (Excel 2010) would be to create a Name (Formula > Define Name) then put the following in the "Refers to" textbox: `=OFFSET('yourSheetName'!$F$6,0,0,COUNTA('yourSheetName'!$F:$F),1)`.

In this example everytime you add data in the F column your Name will be automatically updated. You can do your operations on this specific Name.

Comment: But it involves two sheets, and ultimate aim is if i add data to the database sheet, it should update on the dashboard sheet. I have a lot of sheets, woudnt defining names for each range be complexed?

Comment: @Niva: indeed - represents too much work if you have too many fields.  I supposed you have limited data on your dashboard. Then your solution should be output driven. As Vegard mentioned: you should definitely give us more details.